# How to find maximum repeated characters in a string

Tags: string, find, max, character

I have a string "aaabbb".

Below program returned max repeated value as a.
But here in this case both a and b are max repeated characters.
How can I print that both a and b as max repeated characters.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class MaxRepeatedCharactersInString 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String s = "acakabbba";
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    for(char c : ch)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(c))
        {
            map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    int maxCount = 0;
    char maxChar = ' ';
    System.out.println("Maximum repeated character in String: ");
    for(Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        if(maxCount < entry.getValue())
        {
            maxCount = entry.getValue();
            maxChar = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxChar+"="+maxCount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an extra Stack and a counter to store the maximum repeated characters

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Stack;

class MaxRepeatedCharactersInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aa";
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ch) {
            if (map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        int maxCount = 0;
        int noMax = 0;
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();

        System.out.println("Maximum repeated characters in String: ");
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (maxCount < entry.getValue()) {
                maxCount = entry.getValue();
                noMax = 1;
                st.push(entry.getKey());
            } else if (maxCount == entry.getValue()) {
                noMax++;
                st.push(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < noMax; i++) {
            System.out.println(st.pop() + "=" + maxCount);
        }

    }
}
```